# Import values from the database to a table or something better

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a question about using databases...

```
 string node = Session["node"].ToString();

 SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
 dataConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SumooHAgentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand();
 dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;

 dataCommand.CommandText = ("Select * from xyz where @xyzID= xyzID AND PathType=0")
 dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xyzID", node);

 dataConnection.Open();
 dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 dataConnection.Close();
```

Now there are 5 columns in the table with 5 rows which should return.

I then want to add these values in a table or arraylist so that i can use those values in my code later...

What is the best way to do so????
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them to a `DataTable` - then you'll have a `.Rows` property with 5 rows, and each `DataRow` in the `.Rows` property has five columns which holds those values. Almost like a database in memory.

To do that, just use the `SqlDataAdapter` and its `Fill` method:

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(dataCommand);
dap.Fill(myTable);
```

Or you can read the rows and values with a `DataReader` and then take those and turn each row into an object of type "whatever-it-is" and call a constructor on that object type with those five column values, and stick your resulting five objects into a `List<WhateverItIs>` and you've basically created your own little ORM (Object-relational mapper).

This would require you to use a `SqlDataReader` and do something like this:

```
SqlDataReader dr = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
List<Entity> _list = new List<Entity>();

while(dr.Read())
{ 
   string column1 = dr.GetString(0);
   ...
   string column5 = dr.GetString(4);

   Entity newEntity = new Entity(column1, ......., column5);
   _list.Add(newEntity);
}
```

Whatever works best for you - the DataTable is less work in the initial loading phase, but accessing the data later on is a bit more cumbersome (`MyDataTable.Rows[3].Column["ColunmName"].Value` or something like that) - the "ORM" approach gives you nice objects of a .NET CLR type which you can more easily use, but it's more work initially when loading the data.

Marc

Learning resources:

- [C# Station ADO.NET Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/lesson01.aspx)
- [Using ADO.NET for beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseAcessWithAdoNet1.aspx)
- [ADO.NET Quickstarts on asp.net](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/howto/doc/adoplus/overviewcontents.aspx)

Comment: This is great... but i am not that good with ado.net...
Is there a place where i can read how to add values inta a datatable...
Or can u show me an example.... uv been of great help.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(), you need:

```
SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(dataCommand);
DataTable resultsTable = new DataTable();
a.Fill(resultsTable);
```

The data will then be in the resultsTable object.

Sounds like you need to read up on ADO.NET generally ... DataTables are covered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), there are lots of examples on the web showing how to loop through them and get the data out, for example, [here](http://dotnetperls.com/datatable-foreach).

Comment: I just have a doubt:
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xyzID",node);
Is this right or will it give an error??

Comment: The use of this command is to give the values stored in node to the xyzID in the query... is there a better way to do so??

Comment: The way you are using AddWithValues() looks about right to me. The best way to find out if it gives an error is to actually try and run it!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) method instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Data Access Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203144.aspx) released by Microsoft Patterns & Practices if you don't want to do all the low level ADO.NET plumbing work.